# jQuery animation doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

This animation works in IE, Chrome and Safari, but why not in FF?

http://jsfiddle.net/DRMgQ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-position-x` and `-y` aren't part of the standard (see [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Tracker/issues/9)) and apparently aren't supported in FF: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y.

Comment: Well, somewhat, but I don't think having to use just the x,y version is a great hardship - there's no functional difference, just write a function to change the x/y values so all the string fiddling is in one place.

Comment: Web-related coding is full of dissapointment. Mostly comes from IE

Answer (score 1):

`background-position-x` is a MSIE specific property. Set both coordinates in the standard `background-position` property

Comment: MS & Webkit specific, Opera doesn't count.

Comment: Well, indeed. Anyway, something-specific in a web environment is just as annoying